# why tekton execution unit is pod, not a container?

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Currently I am using `Jenkins on kubernetes` and wanted to migrate to `tekton` because trying achieve CI steps as a code (similar to Helm chart for CD steps). Just wondering about Tekton architecture -

why every task creates different pod rather than creating different containers in a single pod. Creating multiples pod leads resources locking as every pod will hold cpus/memory (default) till pod receives SIGTERM.

Comment: From [the official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/): "*Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes. ...*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wondering about Tekton architecture -
> why every task creates different pod rather than creating different containers in a single pod?

This is a design choice that was made early in the project. They want *Tasks* to be a reusable component with, e.g. parameters and results.

But you are right that it leads to problems when it comes to resource allocation. There are on-going work for executing a whole *Pipeline* within a single Pod, see [Tekton Enhancement Proposal 44](https://github.com/tektoncd/community/blob/main/teps/0044-data-locality-and-pod-overhead-in-pipelines.md)